# sp_reset_connection taking a long time to run

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server

I've got an application where all the sprocs are running nice and quick, but the sp_reset_connection calls between them are taking anything up to 20 seconds. I've looked at locking and blocking but can't see any happening and don't understand how this would effect sp_reset_connection.
Help!

Comment: Are you just now seeing this behavior or has it "always" been there?  This link doesn't help anser your question but provides a nice list of what happens when the proc runs..http://www.sqldev.net/articles/sp_reset_connection/default.html

Comment: Is it causing a problem?

Comment: It's causing a big problem since I'm using connection pool and the next time ado.net uses the connection it sites there and waits for this to complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out what the issue was.
It looks like when you run a trace the data gets written as part of this sproc, this means that if you're tracing into a table and the insert speed isn't stellar everything grinds to a halt.

Comment: Can you expound on this? I'm not sure I understand your answer.